# Doxygen warning: no uniquely matching class member found for 

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen for a C++ project. When I'm building the html doc, I get the following error:

> C:/Amir/Programming/Eclipse C++/CacheOptimization/src/CacheLruNaiveAlgorithm.cpp:19:
>
> warning: no uniquely matching class member found for
>
> `void CacheOpt::CacheLruNaiveAlgorithm::init(TierList &tierList, TierMap *tierMap)`

What could be the source for this warning? What usually causes it?

**Edit:**

My Doxyfile

```
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "Cache Optimization"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 1.0
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "Technion & LSI - Industrial Project"
PROJECT_LOGO           = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = "C:/Amir/Programming/Eclipse C++/CacheOptimization/doc/"
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 8
ALIASES                = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = 
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = YES
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
SYMBOL_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_DIRECTORIES       = NO
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            = 
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = 
INPUT                  = "C:/Amir/Programming/Eclipse C++/CacheOptimization/"
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.d \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.idl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.cs \
                         *.php \
                         *.php3 \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = 
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
HTML_ALIGN_MEMBERS     = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               = 
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHG_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
USE_INLINE_TREES       = NO
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://www.mathjax.org/mathjax
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_LINKS              = NO
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_SCHEMA             = 
XML_DTD                = 
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = NO
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = NO
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = NO
CALL_GRAPH             = NO
CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
DOT_PATH               = 
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
MSCFILE_DIRS           = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

---

---

**Edit:**

Here's a sample method definition/declaration that doxygen is complaining about (I removed some stuff, like the parameter types, because it is IP protected. There are no macros used anywhere):

**Algorithm.h**

```
namespace CacheOpt {
    class Algorithm {
        protected:
            /*..*/
        public:
            virtual void init(/*..*/);
            virtual std::string getName() = 0;
    };
} //CacheOpt
```

**Algorithm.cpp**

```
#include "Algorithm.h"

void
CacheOpt::Algorithm::init(/*..*/) {
    /*..*/
}
```

I get this error here:

> C:/Amir/Programming/Eclipse C++/CacheOptimization/src/Algorithm.cpp:11: warning: no uniquely matching class member found for
> `void CacheOpt::Algorithm::init(/*..*/)`

and it doesn't even identify `Algorithm` as a class! What can I do?

Comment: What are the Doxytags that cause this warning?  What do you have in your Doxyfile?

Comment: @James I pasted my Doxyfile. what are Doxytags?

Comment: Is the line of code causing the warning a function call or a comment block?  Are you trying to remotely associate a comment using the `\function` (or '@function`) tag?

Comment: Have you properly documented the enclosing CacheOpt namespace?

Comment: @Sam does it matter? Other classes in the same namespace are showing up fine.

Answer (score 13):

Possible causes:

- <strike>If you are trying to remotely associate comments with code by using tags like `\function` and `\class`, stop.  Putting the documentation comments immediately before the code in question will automatically associate it, make it more likely that the code maintainer will update the comment when modifying the code, and completely remove the burden of updating function signatures in the comment.</strike>
- A class member with an out-of-class implementation has a source code mismatch between the signatures of declaration and definition.  According to the C++ standard, things like top-level const do not change the signature, but doxygen works on source code and tries to match things using different rules from the compiler.  Typedefs and macros may also play a role, where the compiler sees a definition corresponding to the declaration while doxygen sees two separate functions.  It might be possible to resolve this by telling doxygen to expand certain macros, or it might be necessary to tweak the declaration to exactly match the definition.
- Using the scope operator with namespaces or multiple times in the same name.  Some of doxygen's code assumes that the scope operator is used with types rather than namespaces.  Using a namespace block instead is a reasonable workaround.  I've also seen issues where the scope resolution operator is used more than once, doxygen may keep too many scopes when it moves on to processing the next code snippet.  Keep your code simpler, and doxygen will like it better.

For your code example, this may work better:

```
#include "Algorithm.h"

namespace CacheOpt
{
    void Algorithm::init(/*..*/)
    {
        /*..*/
    }
}
```

If this is a workaround, feel free to use it, but also [file a bug report](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen) on [the doxygen bug tracker](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/query.cgi?format=advanced&product=doxygen).

Comment: I am not trying to associate anything and except for one `\brief` tag in an unrelated class that works, I am not using any tags.

Comment: @Amir: Ok, here's another idea. Also, is the warning occurring on a comment line or source code?

Comment: @Ben it also doesn't recognize an abstract class I have.

Comment: @Amir: thanks, the code snippet gave me a couple other ideas as to what might be going wrong, see edits.

Comment: @Ben sorry - not it. I use this namespace qualifier (this exact namespace) in all my implementations and it works in other classes. Also, Doxygen doesn't identify the class even if I put the init implementation in the header file (in the class declaration) and it's the only implemented method in `Algorithm`, the rest are pure virtual.

Comment: @Amir: Ok, then there must be something in "Algorithm.h" that's breaking doxygen, possibly above the declaration of `class Algorithm` or possibly inside the class.  Can you set Doxyfile to process just that one file, and then pay really close attention to all the warnings it generates?  Also turn on SOURCE_BROWSER and look at the source code colorization of the generated HTML file for Algorithm.h source code.

Comment: @Ben I don't know what the problem is, but I found a workaround - forward declare the class inside a namespace and then declaring it outside it (`namespace CacheOpt { class Algorithm; } class CacheOpt::Algorithm { ... }`), but this is still a workaround. I would love to see a solution where I don't have to abuse my code, so I'm leaving the bounty open :)

Comment: I think that doxygen isn't seeing the class definition at all, due to something in your code that's too complicated for it to handle.  When you add the forward declaration, it's documenting the class solely based on that.  Without seeing your actual I can't be of much help tracking down the problem, but what happens if you commented out all members of the class, would doxygen then see it?  If yes, you can add them back just a couple at a time until you find the problem.

Comment: Hello I had the same error message from doxygen and Ben's suggestion (write `namespace MyNamespace { MyMethod()... } ` instead of `MyNamespace::MyMethod()...` in the .cpp file) fixed it. I just thought I'd add my feedback so that it helps the next users facing this problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue where the ctor definition used a namespace alias `fs = std::filesystem;` and the declaration in the class didn't. But it only became a problem once a second ctor was added.